# now it seems / as I see it now / as now I see it / to see it now / as for now / as of now What's the phrase I am looking for?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, sentence

I came up with the following phrases to start the sentence, but I am not sure which one is proper.

> Now it seems, that ...
>
> As I see it now, ...
>
> As now I see it, ...
>
> To see it now, ...
>
> As for now, ...
>
> As of now, ...

My sentence is:

> **INSERT HERE** the “learning-by-doing" philosophy did play an important role in consolidating my undergraduate knowledge.

The context of this sentence is that I did not realize the importance of the philosophy before, but finally, I do now when I look back.

I'm not sure if any of those is proper to fit the context; if not, please suggest better ones. Thanks!!

**p.s.** I am doing some formal writing, so I would like to make sure the usage of words is both proper and formal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of those you suggested, the only one that really works is *"As I see it now, ..."*

However, another option would be something like this:

> Looking back now, the “learning-by-doing" philosophy did play an important role in consolidating my undergraduate knowledge.

or

> In hindsight, the “learning-by-doing" philosophy did play an important role in consolidating my undergraduate knowledge.

Comment: +1 for the pragmatic marker (showing [temporal] point of view) 'In hindsight', which I'd suggest. Perhaps 'heuristic approach' for ' "learning-by-doing" philosophy'?